# format exception unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, exception, declaration

This code is giving format exception unhandled!

I want to get the numerical values from the textboxes. Is there any other method i can  adopt?

This form(form2) is used as a custom message box, which is called  twice from my main form(form1). Therefore the arrays are of size 3.

```
Int32[] g = new Int32[3];
Int32[] h = new Int32[3];
int TwoClicks = 0;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    g[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text));
    h[TwoClicks] = (Int32.Parse(textBox3.Text) * 60 + Int32.Parse(textBox4.Text));

}
```

Comment: When you debug your code what are your input values from the textboxes?

Comment: Are you sure the contents from the textboxes are int's? Can you show us some sample input? When debugging, on what line does it throw the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on what do u want to achive. u can use `TryParse` method to get parsed value and information if parsing was sucesful, it there was error u can do something appropriate to the situation like return 0 as value of Textbox. Other thing u can do is suround the code u have with `try cach` and do something when exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using a List:

```
    List<int> g = new List<int>();
    List<int> h = new List<int>();

    int text1, text2, text3, text4;
    int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out text1);
    int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out text2);
    int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out text3);
    int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out text4);

    g.Add(text1 * 60 + text2);
    h.Add(text3 * 60 + text4);
```